# Lost old Indian passport. How to receive Indian Visa with American passport

Tags: visas, passports, indian-citizens, lost-documents

I lost my old Indian passport. I need to get Indian Visa stamp on my American passport. What is the procedure for that?

Comment: You apply through the nearest Indian embassy or consulate.

Comment: You apply for an OCI card.

Comment: India does not permit dual citizenship. When you received your American passport, you would have had to surrender your Indian passport. Your question is not clear as it is written.

Comment: If you are an Indian citizen, you need to check whether you're obliged to enter India on your Indian passport. If so, you need to apply for a new passport, not a visa. And did you report the passport as lost?